# Airflow execution Macros returning wrong value

Tags: date, templates, macros, airflow

Im trying to get the prev_execution_date using Airflow`s macros but only the current execution_date is returned regardless what Macro I call

This is the task code that i`m using

```
get_last_run = BashOperator(
    task_id='get_last_run',
    xcom_push=True,
    bash_command='echo "{{ execution_date }}, {{ prev_execution_date }}, {{next_execution_date}}"',
    dag=dag,
)
```

And this are the returned values (the exactly same):

`[2019-10-07 16:26:41,781] {{bash_operator.py:123}} INFO - 2019-10-07T16:23:44.864787+00:00, 2019-10-07T16:23:44.864787+00:00, 2019-10-07T16:23:44.864787+00:00`

Do someone knows whats happening and why the macros arent working properly?

Comment: is your DAG running on [schedule](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/models/dag.py#L93) or are you manually triggering it?

Comment: Im running manually, 
did some tests with the scheduled run and it works properly,
its a shame that macros only work with the scheduler.
Is there a way to get this data using the manual trigger?